# Get src parameter value from <img> with scraper

Tags: web-scraping, rust, reqwest

I want to get a `url` from `<img>` (inside of src parameter) html tag using `scraper`.
I've tried this code

```rust
let image_selector = scraper::Selector::parse("#photoInner > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > img").unwrap();
let mut inner_image: String = next_document
                    .select(&image_selector)
                    .flat_map(|el| el.attr())
                    .collect();
println!("{:?}", inner_image);
```

But I'm getting that `attr` method not found in `ElementRef<'_>`.
I'm not sure how to chain the methods to make this work.

HTML looks like this

```html
<img onerror="this.src='/ui/utility/common/svg/iconI_no-image.svg?s=1&amp;w=350&amp;h=350';" alt="" src="https://image1.homes.jp/smallimg/image.php?file=%2Fdata%2F1700013%2Fsale%2Fimage%2F0010012-1.jpg&amp;width=620">
```

Comment: Did you try `|el| el.value().attr("src")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let img_selector = Selector::parse("img").unwrap();
    for img_src in document.select(&img_selector) {
        // Extract SRC value
        if let Some(src) = img_src.value().attr("src") {
            println!("src: {}", src);
        }
    }
}
```